# run ffmpeg commands from my own project

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I'm starting a project where I want ppl to upload videos of a talk and a the video of slides for that talk and want to merge them (to play at the same time) and then show results.

My question is:
Is it possible to do that from code? if it is, can you point me to the right doc?
I was able to do it running command line, but as I want this to run on a server with different ppl uploading their videos I think this would not be the best approach.
I have a preference for Java if it's possible to do it, but I can manage to use other languages what do you guys suggest?

The idea would be to have a service where I can point the urls of the videos stored in my server and it would merge them and save file where I can later stream. With different ppl uploading videos at the same time and being able to watch the result in a reasonable amount of time.

I used this tutorial to test:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos

Thanks for your time

Comment: How would you get the timing correct for when to display the slides?

Comment: The slides is just another video that is synchronized in time with the talk video.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was a PowerPoint file or similar. Can you describe how you visualize the "merge" (overlay, picture-in-picture, side-by-side, etc)?

Comment: The idea is after the user uploads this two files create a new file in the server with ffmpeg and stream that video into a player.

Comment: The idea is side by side but that is not really the most important part of the problem.